# How to connect my program to a certain website in JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, web

Good Day guys,

I'm a student right now and want to learn how could I connect my fresh program to
our school's website.

Though I'm still developing this program, to be able to continue to progress of my program is to know how could I connect it to the said website.

and I want to connect the user and pass text field to this site

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2gEk.png

So if the user enters their user and pass to my program . I want it to sync to the website above

After that look to this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIp9K.png

I want to get all these information and put these informations to my program because I'm still developing my GUI's for these info where I will put them into it.

So Please help me what should I do , or just a brief instruction.

**My goal is to create a GWA calculator in a beautiful environment
so I'm asking how could i connect it to the website.**

*I will post my code if needed*

*Please check all those pics because I cant post images , needs 10 reputation*

Comment: here's my program LOGIN FORM

http://i.stack.imgur.com/jdYzz.png

Comment: How do you think browser handles logging process?

Comment: @Pshemo 
What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are asking how to capture information from a website with no formal API. There are several methods of capturing this information most of them implement the concept of a [Reverse Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). These [website scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) utilities are meant to capture information from a site that has no formal API.

However, you will want to be cognizant of the **TOS (Terms of Service)** and **legal ramifications** of implementing this method as the absence of a formal API usually means the information contained within the site is meant to stay there. Also, if the format of the page changes you will be left with modifying your implementation of the website scraping utility to capture the information again.

You may be better off contacting the website admin or company and inquiring about an API that can be used.

Comment: Bro , I just need a simple program like internet explorer that's all i need like im going to create a program then the user and pass will depends on WEBSITE Login.. tell if u get it?

Comment: A .NET application that would offer programmatic functionality similar to a browser is [WatiN](http://watin.org/). I believe that program offers the same functionality of IE JavaScript and all.